# Check if NSColorPanel is 'sampling'?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nscolor, nscolorpanel

In `NSColorPanel` the user can click on the pipette symbol to sample a colour from anywhere on the screen.

Our app uses popovers to ask for optional data (like color) that we hide once the user clicks outside of the popover.

However if an `NSColorPanel` is launched from the popover to pick a color and the user selects the pipette to sample a color it would be valid to click anywhere on screen to sample the color - while the '**sampling**' mode is active.

The `NSColorPanel` doesn't appear to provide a way to query the mode, though..

Is there any way (API, notifications, KVO, ..) to find out whether the panel is currently in sampling mode, i.e. a click outside of our popover is supposed to sample a color, not make the popover go away..?